# You have requested a non-existent service "phpexcel"

Tags: php, symfony, phpexcel

I know there are some questions almost identical but none of them seems to be my case.

I have a symfony 2.8.3 project that reads and imports data from an excel file into mysql database. Its all working nice on localhost but in the last 48 hours I've been trying to get it working on my server. Its a shared hosting, with no SSH access to the linux.

When I am trying to load it from the server I get this error: "You have requested a non-existent service "phpexcel"."

Comment: Can you add the `phpexcel` service declaration (services.yml) to your question ? If you just deployed your application to your server and the service was added in the last deployment, you'll need to clear the cache (maybe manually by removing all files in the cache directory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to use service from [ExcelBundle](https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle). But that bundle is not loaded. Check if you have it added for production env.

```
$bundles = array(
    // ...
    new Liuggio\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle(),
);
```

Don't forget to clear cache on production environment after any config (`AppKernel.php` also) change.

To clear cache run `php app/console cache:clear`. You can also add env parameter: `--env=dev` or `--env=prod` - depending on your env. If it don't help then just remove all content of `app/cache/` directory (or `var/cache/` in case of Symfony3 app)

Answer (score 1):

Pawel answered correctly, but something is missing: after you add this line: `new Liuggio\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle(),` to the `AppKernel.php` file, inside the  `$bundles` array, don't forget to clear the cache: delete the file from `app/cache/dev` in case you're in developer mode or `app/cache/prod` in case on production mode.

Comment: It shouldn't be required to clear cache on dev env. Symfony will find out that new bundle. On prod any config change require clearing cache. If my answer is correct - can you mark it as it?

Comment: yes Pawel, if you extend your question with the cache problem. I can assure you its needed. Thanks!